# getting error while aggregating a huge string with xmlagg

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I am trying to aggregate a String using `xmlagg` but i am facing error. here is the xmlagg

```
select  
            apex_string.format(t1.col_heading, null, null, 1, 2, null)  
          || rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,apex_string.format(t2.col_heading, null, null, da.n_service, case da.gid when 15 then 3 else 1 end, coalesce(da.service_type, 'Grand Total')),'').EXTRACT('//text()') order by da.c ).GetClobVal(),',')
        , min(da.gid)  
      from  
          data_aggs da  
            cross join std_template t1  
            cross join std_template t2  
      where  
          da.balance_type is null  
      and da.gid in (11, 15)  
      group by  
          t1.col_heading
```

When i run this i found below error

`[Error] Execution (132: 14): ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`

Comment: What is `DA.GID`'s datatype?

Comment: Its character type

Comment: Then - in CASE - compare it to strings, not numbers

Comment: can you give an example in answer

Comment: Sure; I posted it, have a look. Hopefully, it'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i was expecting so far

```
select  
          xmlconcat(  
              xmlparse(content apex_string.format(t1.col_heading, null, null, 1, 2, null))  
            , xmlagg(xmlparse(content apex_string.format(t2.col_heading, null, null, da.n_service, case da.gid when 15 then 3 else 1 end, coalesce(da.service_type, 'Grand Total'))) order by da.c))  
        , min(da.gid)  
      from  
          data_aggs da  
            cross join std_template t1  
            cross join std_template t2  
      where  
          da.balance_type is null  
      and da.gid in (11, 15)  
      group by  
          t1.col_heading
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant by saying that - if `DA.GID`'s datatype is `VAR(CHAR)2` - you should compare it to strings, not numbers. Note lines 4, 5 and 14.

```
SQL> select     apex_string.format(t1.col_heading, null, null, 1, 2, null)
  2               || rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement
  3                    (e, apex_string.format(t2.col_heading, null, null, da.n_service,
  4                          case da.gid when '15' then '3'       --> here
  5                                      else '1'                 --> here
  6                          end,
  7                          coalesce(da.service_type, 'Grand Total')), '').extract('//text()')
  8                          order by da.c ).getclobval(), ','),
  9             min(da.gid)
 10  from       data_aggs da
 11  cross join std_template t1
 12  cross join std_template t2
 13  where      da.balance_type is null
 14  and        da.gid in ( '11', '15')                            --> here
 15  group by   t1.col_heading
 16  ;
```

**[EDIT]**

Applying `TO_NUMBER` to `DA.GID` in `CASE`, but leaving it *as is* in line 14.

```
  4                          case to_number(da.gid) when 15 then 3       --> here
  5                                      else 1                          --> here
  6                          end,

 14  and        da.gid in ('11', '15')                                   --> here
```

Comment: Now getting `[Error] Execution (132: 125): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
`

Comment: Which line is line 132 in your code? If NUMBER is expected, maybe the opposite would work (but only if DA.GID contains only numerics, although its datatype is CHAR. I edited the message, see if it helps.

Comment: `|| rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, apex_string.format(t2.col_heading, null, null, da.n_service,case to_number(da.gid) when 15 then 3 else 1 end, coalesce(da.service_type, 'Grand Total')), '').extract('//text()')` This is line 132 i have changed as per your updated answer but now error is `[Error] Execution (132: 19): ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
`

Comment: Bah! And we're back where we were at the beginning, no improvement whatsoever :(

Comment: yup ! i have tried whatever u suggested but really i didn't getting to know why is this happening

Comment: That sting you're aggregating: how long do you expect it to be? If less than 4000 characters, see if LISTAGG would help (so that you'd avoid XMLAGG). If nothing else, it is simpler to use.

Comment: No i have string more than 4000 characters even 30 times of 4000 you can say infinit. thats why i was trying to use xmlagg

Comment: Actually this is a huge query creating pivot of some huge data i just shared particular part which was creating issue for me

Comment: I thought it was a part of some *bigger picture* (as Oracle complains about line 132). I wish I could help, but I don't have any other ideas, sorry. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: yeah sure no problem ,, still many thanks for your time and help.. Good Luck

Comment: Good luck to you too; currently, you need it more than I do :)

Comment: Yes i think so , if you want to go in some more details please see this post
`https://community.oracle.com/thread/4267490`

Comment: I did, thank you. You've got assistance from some respected OTN forum members who know much more about all of that than I do. Hopefully, you'll manage to make it work, although it seems to be a complex problem.

Comment: Ok i am going to update the answer to help you and others how this issue is handled

Comment: Thank you for letting us know; I'm glad if you fixed it.